# useEffect not running and is causing an undefined variable problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to fetch a particular string using the `useRouter`, after which I am using that same string to fetch a specific document from firebase, the aforementioned action is happening in the `useEffect` function, but the `useEffect` function is not running.

The code compilation is directly jumping to the return statement, which then gives me an undefined error because the variables have no value as they get a value in the `useEffect` function. Following is my code:

```
const CheckIn = () => {
  const [room, setRoom] = useState();
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
  console.log('loading:' +loading)
  let currentUserUID = "";

  const router = useRouter();
  const request = router.query;
  console.log(request);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!router.isReady) return;
      console.log("Useffect has ran");
      if (loading) {
        return <div>Authenticating</div>;
      } else {
        currentUserUID = user.uid;
        console.log(currentUserUID);
        let roomRef = collection(db, currentUserUID.toString());
        const data = query(
          roomRef,
          where(documentId(), "==", request.roomID.toString())
        );
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(data);
        console.log(querySnapshot);
        const docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          data.id = doc.id;
          return data;
        });

        console.log(docs[0]);
        setRoom(docs[0]);
      }
    })();
  }, [loading]);

  console.log(room);

  return (
    <>
    <Head>
      Check In
    </Head>
    <div className="grid grid-cols-12 full-h">
      <NavigationBar />
      <div className="col-span-10">
        <div>
          <h1>Check In for {room.guests.numberOfGuests}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6 "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CheckIn;
```

I have tried using the `router.isReady` function in the `useEffet` hook, but it seems that the useEffect function is being completely ignored.

Comment: Hi Skrrubs! I pasted an answer, check it and let me know please.

Comment: @yousoumar It still is not working for some reason, however, in my code, if I don't access the `room` variable, it seems to be working fine. But, if I access the room variable in my return method it still gives the same error that it is not defined, but that is because the useEffect method is not running. If you want me to try anything else please let me know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try my last edit, please. I think the loading is becoming false before the data is fetched. And it would be my pleasure if I could help.

Comment: @yousoumar The useEffect function is working now, thanks. Just another thing, in your answer code, it should be `!room` instead of `room`.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake. Thanks for letting me know, and have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having that `return <div>Authenticating</div>` in your `useEffect` is incorrect. You need to call that outside in your root component, like so:

```js
const CheckIn = () => {
  const [room, setRoom] = useState();
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
  let currentUserUID = "";

  const router = useRouter();
  const request = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (loading) return;

      currentUserUID = user.uid;
      let roomRef = collection(db, currentUserUID.toString());
      const data = query(roomRef, where(documentId(), "==", request.roomID.toString()));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(data);
      const docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        data.id = doc.id;
        return data;
      });

      setRoom(docs[0]);
    })();
  }, [loading]);

  if (loading || !room) {
    return <div>Authenticating and fetching data...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>Check In</Head>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-12 full-h">
        <NavigationBar />
        <div className="col-span-10">
          <div>
            <h1>Check In for {room.guests.numberOfGuests}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6 "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CheckIn;
```